# How to enable an actions option

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I can't seem to figure out how to enable an actions column on my web part, for if I wanted to choose to export a list to excel.
[image: Here's an example of what I want to top bar of my list to look like]

Comment: That's a picture of a tool bar at the top of a list that I want, not what I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much information to go by here so I've made a few assumptions. Apologies if this doesn't help. I'll keep an eye on this and update the answer as more information comes to light.

I'm assuming that you are not talking about a web part that you've created yourself, and are talking about a SharePoint list app that has been added to a page in a SharePoint Online site.

What you need to do is to edit the page that the website is displaying on and then hover over the web part until you see a checkbox in the top right with a down arrow next to it. Click the arrow and in the menu that appears click `Edit Web Part`.

Once you are editing the web part look under the heading `List Views` and change the `Toolbar Type` to be `Full Toolbar`.